# Changing the formatting of search results depending on category searched within

Tags: wordpress, search, forms, categories

- I have two search forms setup in the sidebar.
- Each form is configured to search within a specific category.
- 'Members' and 'News'.

Is it possible to change the text displayed before the search results depending on which search form I used?

Answer (score 0):

http://return-true.com/2010/10/using-multiple-search-forms-in-wordpress/